# What makes Sequential Bayesian Filtering and Smoothing tractable?

Tags: bayesian-networks, bayes-theorem, bayesian-probability, kalman-filter

I'm currently diving into the **Bayesian world** and I find it pretty fascinating.
I've so far understood that applying the **Bayes' Rule**, i.e.
$$\text{posterior} = \frac{\text{likelihood}\times \text{prior}}{\text{evidence}}$$
are most of the time intractable because of the high dimensional parameter space in the denominator.
One way to solve this is by using a prior **conjugate** to the likelihood, as then the analytical form of the posterior is known and calculations are simplified.

So far so good. Now I've read about bayesian **sequential filtering and smoothing** techniques such as the Kalman Filter or Rauch-Tung-Striebel Smoother (find references [here](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://users.aalto.fi/%7Essarkka/pub/cup_book_online_20131111.pdf)). As far as I understood,  assuming a time step $k$,  instead of calculating the complete posterior distribution $p(X_k|Y_k)$ with $X=[x_1, ...,x_k]$ and $Y=[y_1,...y_k]$, a Markov Chain is assumed and only the marginal $p(x_k|Y_k)$ is estimated in a recursive manner. That is, the posterior calculate at time step $k$ serves as prior for the next time step. I guess, **Bayes' Rule** is somehow involved in these calculations

Furthermore, both techniques assume the posterior always to be **Gaussian** and therefore closed-form solutions are obtained. **Now I was wondering what restriction does make the whole process tractable, i.e. eliminates the need to compute the evidence?**

I guess it's the **Gaussian assumption**, i.e. the prior, the predicted, and the posterior distribution are all assumed to be Gaussian, and therefore updated distributions are obtained without computing the evidence - **is this correct and does this refer to conjugate distributions?**

Or is it the fact that we assume a **Markov Chain** and do not consider all states at each time step?

Comment: It's the Markov assumption which let's you forget the prior states.

Comment: so the Gaussian assumptions of prior and posterior distribution have nothing todo with it?